# How to count unique lines intersecting with polygons?

Tags: qgis, intersection

[image: Intersection]

Like u can see on the attached picture i did an intersection with a Raster (purple squares) and the red lines. What i need to know is the count of joins each line has for each square. What makes this impossible is the fact that the lines are split where they intersect itself. They are not split where they intersect other lines.  Is there any option where i am able to get one line for each time a line crosses a square ?

I am not sure if its plausible what i want. Let me know if u need some more information.

Comment: Do the split lines share a common attribute value, like line ID? Do all lines in one box share a common attribute value, like box ID? If yes to both, then Dissolve based on those attributes and count using the QGIS version of ArcGIS' Summary Statistics (sorry, not sure what that is).